# Galois correspondence of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{28})/\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory

How to determine the Galois correspondence of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{28})/\mathbb{Q}$, where $\zeta_{28}$ is a primitive 28-th root of unity?

It seems that in [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132169/a-complete-picture-of-the-lattice-of-subfields-for-a-cyclotomic-extension-over) only $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}$ for $n=p^k$ is discussed.

Comment: Do you mean, that you want to compute that Galois group?

Comment: no, I meant that I want to the determine the diagrams of intermediate fields and subgroups of the Galois group.

Comment: Have you identified the Galois group?

Comment: It is $(\mathbb{Z}/28\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Comment: It seems that in [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132169/a-complete-picture-of-the-lattice-of-subfields-for-a-cyclotomic-extension-over) only $\mathbb{Q}(n)/\mathbb{Q}$ for $n=p^k$ is discussed.